# Python Fabric on FreeBSD cannot execute Binary

Tags: python, bash, unix, fabric, bsd

My simple Fab file cannot be run on my FreeBSD system:

```
from fabric.api import run, env
env.shell = '/usr/local/bin/bash'   #Fabric doesn't know where to get bash on BSD correctly

def host_type():
    run('uname')
```

First I get an error about the shell, which I can fix by specifying the shell variable as shown.
But then I still have the error:

> /usr/bin/uname: /usr/bin/uname: cannot execute binary file.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like according to the man pages of bash(1):

> Bash is an **sh**-compatible command language interpreter that executes commands read from the start input or from a file.

Meaning the only input we can give bash is a script or input via a stdin pipe. But with the **-c** option:

> -c If the **-c** option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument *command_string*,...

So the solution be to use the shell with the **-c** option is as follows:

```
env.shell = '/usr/local/bin/bash -c'
```

And then works perfectly, I don't know why the shell for fabric is so strange for a unix system when it's intended to work on servers.

Comment: From the [docs / FAQS](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/faq.html#my-remote-system-doesn-t-have-bash-installed-by-default-do-i-need-to-install-bash): "While Fabric is written with 6bash in mind, it’s not an absolute requirement." So if you want to use FreeBSD, which doesn't use bash by default (["Linux users are often surprised to find that Bash is not the default shell in FreeBSD. In fact, Bash is not included in the default installation."](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/linux-users/shells.html)). then you need to configure Fabric accordingly, as they describe in the FAQ.